# XCode 4 - Base SDK == Latest iOS (iOS 4.3)

Tags: ios4, xcode4, radix

To continue in my post-XCode 4 upgrade confusion, i came across this....

My Build Settings has Base SDK as iOS 4.3.

Now back in XCode 3.x days I remember 2 things:

1. The Base SDK was always set to iOS 4.0.
2. The target device was set to iphone 3.0 (to ensure greatest iphone audience).

What consequence is there for this Base SDK?
I mean, if SDK 4.0 provides support for features that only iOS4/iPhone4) provides, then why are these two separate build settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose iOS 4.0 as your base SDK, but as long as you do not use APi's that are 4.0 and up your code should run on 3.x unless you used apis that were only in 3.2 and so on =)

Always a good thing to check the availability of methods when you look in the class reference.

I recommend using 4.x stuff.. because the people that use 3.0 are not worth supporting ( Only the really old devices are still running that, iPhone 1 -- most users have upgraded by now to an iPhone 3Gs or 4 ), the features you get in 4.x, including GCD are awesome.

Comment: hmm. i always thought the ios 3.0 crowd was a sizeable group, thus my vow to always support that version. maybe it's time i reconsider. would like to see some stats on this if that sort of thing is available.

Comment: Well if you think about it, the only iOS device that cannot be upgraded to SDK 4.x is the first generation iPhone/iPod Touch, and that was released 4 years ago. It really isn't worth supporting that old a device any longer. Most iPhone users have upgraded, as Antwan stated. I don't know where to find stats unfortunately.

Comment: @Alvin If you do not need Apis from iOS 4, you should try to support it yes, I do agree on that... My application for the mac doesn't support Tiger though I'd like to. Then again if I didn't have to support the leopard fags I'd have GCD at my disposal :P